# How to ref class static method in current class variable?

Tags: python

does anyone have idea how to refer to class static method in the class attributes? for example:

```
class A(object):

    var = A.staticMethod1   # this line doesn't work, as A has not be defined yet.

    @staticmethod
    def staticMethod1(*param):
        pass
```

Comment: You've got an attribute already. It's `staticMethod1`. Can you explain why you want another?

Comment: I need to call diff method base on the name of the var.

Comment: That doesn't explain anything.

Comment: `staticMethod1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class blocks are just temporary scopes, so, it's actually pretty simple.  Just move the alias below the method definition, and take off the class name (since you're in scope directly)

```
class A(object):

    @staticmethod
    def staticMethod1(*param):
        pass

    var = staticMethod1
```